# Ruby - Convert a string to Date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a string with the format like

> "25/04/14",  "12/03/13"  (dd/mm/yy)

how to convert it into date format

> 25-04-2014 , 12-03-2013

in ruby.

Comment: `Date.strptime("25/04/14", '%d/%m/%y').strftime("%d-%m-%Y") => 25-04-2014`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want date object

```
date_string = "25/04/14"
date = Date.strptime(date_string, "%d/%m/%y")
```

if you want `25-04-2014` format string

```
new_format = date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
```

Comment: The year will be 2 digits, required is 4. Please pay attention.

Comment: No you didn't year should be last, yours returns `2014-04-25` :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime):

```
Date.strptime('25/04/14', '%d/%m/%y')
# => Fri, 25 Apr 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way out is as under:

```
require 'date'
Date.strptime('25/04/14' , '%d/%m/%y')
#<Date:2014-04-25>
```

Comment: The input is a two-digit year - you'll get `"14-04-2025"`

Comment: @UriAgassi Oops my bad

Answer (score 0):

```
Date.strptime(s, '%d/%m/%y').strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
```

console:

```
2.1.5 :018 > Date.strptime(s, '%d/%m/%y').strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
 => "25-04-2014"
```